# Should I care about current theme?

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes, controltemplate

Authoring a WPF control template, consisting of only a Grid, some TextBlocks and a couple of Buttons, do I really need to worry about the current theme on user's machine? Will it look crippled or otherwise imperfect on a machine running on Win8? I do not have access to a Win8 machine, so can't ensure, but [this forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/510d453b-60ee-428d-af81-9094b5ab9daf/how-to-make-a-control-template-or-templates-that-respect-all-windows-themes?forum=wpf) post suggests that "simple" controls are not affected by the current theme. If that is the case, which controls are included in the list of simple contorls?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all standard controls come without any styles applied to them on Win8.

**Update:**

I am sorry it looks like I was wrong. There is a specific Theme for  Windows 8. It is called Aero2.NormalColor.xaml

You can find more info about it here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3dd4221-af4d-4ae4-a983-895db12ebcd0/what-is-the-theme-name-for-a-wpf-application-on-windows-8

Here is where to find the theme file itself:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d05228d4-3dc2-4241-84a1-236a7a1f2d65/where-is-the-xaml-source-for-the-aero2normalcolor-theme

More here
http://brianlagunas.com/add-windows-8-aero-theme-support-to-your-wpf-custom-control/

**Update 2:**
And here is how to force your application to use specific Theme ignoring windows version:
http://www.kennethham.com/wp/2010/11/force-wpf-to-use-windows-7aero-theming-in-classic-mode/

Comment: Does this mean I can forget about user's current theme and that my control will appear exactly same on all Win7 and Win8 machines? If yes, do you have any official reference to that claim?